# SQL - UNION does not order second SELECT

Tags: mysql, union

I`m trying to solve this challenge:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-pads

My solution is this in MySQL:

```
(SELECT CONCAT(Name,'(',SUBSTR(Occupation,1,1),')') FROM Occupations ORDER BY Name)
UNION
(SELECT CONCAT('There are total ', COUNT(Occupation), ' ',LOWER(Occupation),'s.') AS total FROM Occupations 
GROUP BY Occupation 
ORDER BY total);
```

However it fails to ORDER BY total.

```
Ashley(P) 
Samantha(A) 
Julia(D) 
Britney(P) 
Maria(P) 
Meera(P) 
Priya(D) 
Priyanka(P) 
Jennifer(A) 
Ketty(A) 
Belvet(P) 
Naomi(P) 
Jane(S) 
Jenny(S) 
Kristeen(S) 
Christeen(S) 
Eve(A) 
Aamina(D) 
There are total 4 actors. 
There are total 3 doctors. 
There are total 7 professors. 
There are total 4 singers.
```

If I only run

```
SELECT CONCAT('There are total ', COUNT(Occupation), ' ',LOWER(Occupation),'s.') AS total FROM Occupations 
GROUP BY Occupation 
ORDER BY total
```

it does order:

```
There are total 3 doctors. 
There are total 4 actors. 
There are total 4 singers. 
There are total 7 professors.
```

Comment: A side note: `UNION` is made to remove duplicates from the results. Do you even have duplicates? The query doesn't suggest that. Probably you can do with a simple `UNION ALL` and thus save execution time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct.  The ordering of the result set is based *only* on the outermost `order by`.  This is true for `union` as for other operations.

```
(SELECT CONCAT(Name,'(', SUBSTR(Occupation,1,1),')') AS total
 FROM Occupations
 ORDER BY Name
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT CONCAT('There are total ', COUNT(Occupation), ' ', LOWER(Occupation), 's.') AS total
 FROM Occupations 
 GROUP BY Occupation 
)
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN total LIKE 'There are total%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
         Total;
```

This assumes that `Name` never starts with `'There are total'`, which seems likely.

Answer (score 2):

The result gets ordered by the final `ORDER BY` clause. This is `ORDER BY total`, i.e. by the first column. (You only give this name in the second part of UNION, which would probably not work in another DBMS. You should name the columns you select in a `UNION` query in the first part.)

You want to get names first, then the aggregates. Then you want names alphabetically, aggregates by count (i.e. *not* alphabetically, not 1 -> 10 -> 11 -> 2 -> 20 ..., but 1 -> 2 -> 10 -> 11 -> 20 ...) then by job name. You can create sortkeys for this task. I assume you really want `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`. If I am wrong, change it :-)

```
SELECT txt
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    CONCAT(Name, '(', SUBSTR(Occupation, 1, 1), ')') as txt,
    1 as sortkey1,
    CONCAT(Name, '(', SUBSTR(Occupation, 1, 1), ')') as sortkey2
  FROM Occupations
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    CONCAT('There are total ', COUNT(Occupation), ' ', LOWER(Occupation), 's.') AS txt,
    2 + COUNT(Occupation) as sortkey1,
    LOWER(Occupation) as sortkey2
  FROM Occupations 
  GROUP BY Occupation 
) data
ORDER BY sortkey1, sortkey2;
```

Comment: Took me a while understand what `2 + COUNT(Occupation) as sortkey1,` was for. but very good.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten! It works but could you please explain it in more details?
1- why in the firts select you do apparently the same CONCAT twise?
2- what is 1 as sortkey1?
3- why 2+CONCAT inthe second select?

Comment: **First Select:**  The first concat is for display the text, the second is for sorting. So order will put all `1's` together and then sort by sortkey2. **Second Select:** The `2 + COUNT(Occupation)` 2 is so everyone in this group is after the first one `1's`, then the `count`, is to make profesion with `2 total` appear before `10 total` because if you sort by text `'10' > '2'`

Comment: To resume, he separate text to display from sort key because the values are different on each `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

@gordon answer is fine

But for a more generic case you have to create a "dummy" field to separate each group.

```
(SELECT CONCAT(Name,'(', SUBSTR(Occupation,1,1),')') as Name,
        0 as dummy
 FROM Occupations
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT CONCAT('There are total ', COUNT(Occupation), ' ', LOWER(Occupation), 's.') AS Name,
        1 as dummy
 FROM Occupations 
 GROUP BY Occupation 
)
ORDER BY dummy, name
```

Comment: Thanks! so here I have two columns, right? one with dummy and other with CONCAT result?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers and my best understanding I came with this solution that works for this case:

```
    (SELECT CONCAT(Name,'(',SUBSTR(Occupation,1,1),')') as total FROM Occupations ORDER BY Name)
UNION ALL
(SELECT CONCAT('There are total ', COUNT(Occupation), ' ',LOWER(Occupation),'s.') AS total FROM Occupations 
GROUP BY Occupation) 
ORDER BY total;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
you can give two different select queries whith out UNION/ UNION ALL.

```
SELECT Concat(NAME, '(', Substr(occupation, 1, 1), ')') AS Result 
FROM occupations 
ORDER  BY NAME;


SELECT Concat('There are a total of ', Count(*), ' ', Lower(occupation), 's.') 
FROM   occupations 
GROUP  BY occupation 
ORDER  BY Count(*), occupation;
```

Answer (score 0):

(SELECT CONCAT(Name,'(', SUBSTR(Occupation,1,1),')') as Name

FROM Occupations
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ', COUNT(Occupation), ' ', LOWER(Occupation), 's.') AS Name
FROM Occupations
GROUP BY Occupation
)
ORDER BY  Name